# Distorted UVs on a single object in my Three.js scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, maya

I've been putting together a 3d model of a house and right now I'm stuck with yet another aggravating roadblock like those three.js has gotten me accustomed to.

I'm creating my scene in Maya and using the OBJ exporter to write obj and mtl files that I then import into three.js. I have about 9 objects in my scene, ungrouped, children only to the world, history deleted, and with texture maps that have ambient occlusion and lighting baked into them assigned to them via shadingMaps.

I've actually had little luck actually using the mtl file, so I just copied my texture maps and loaded them separately and created materials out of them in three.js.

Now, all of these objects look just fine in the browser, except for the simplest one, the walls and floor object. This is what the object looks like in Maya:
[image: Screenshot from Maya]

As you can see, a rather simple mesh with minimal polys looking beautiful in Maya.

I've learned that when I export objects into obj files, only one UV channel is supported, so I copy my UVs into the default channel and delete all other UV channels before exporting. This is the UV map:
[image: screenshot from textureEditor]

But when I assign this material in the browser, I get a strange texture distortion like so:
[image: Screenshot from Browser]

It's like the UVs are all over the place. I would seriously doubt that my approach is anywhere close to being on target if it weren't for those 8 other (more complex, mind you) objects which all display fine. 
[image: Screenshot from Browser], including part of the wall that I've cut out of the problematic piece, which is part of the bathroom.

Does anyone have a clue as to how I can troubleshoot this? I've tried exporting straight to js from Maya, but I'm having even more problems with that approach. I've tried converting the obj file into js using the packaged browser-based converter. I've spent days on this and am not making any progress.

Here's some relevant code.

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true} );

var wallTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("obj/final_walls.jpg");
var wallMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0x929EAC, map:wallTexture} );

var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader( manager );
loader.load( 'obj/wallOnly.obj','obj/wallOnly.mtl', function ( object ) {
    object.children[2].material = wallMaterial; 
    floorplan.add(object);
    camera.lookAt( object );
} );
```

Please help!!

Comment: You have meshes in your scene graph with 0 faces. Your mesh that does have faces, (812), has a different number of `faceVertexUv`s, (810). In any event, see if this utility helps you track down the problem: http://threejs.org/examples/misc_uv_tests.html.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried it out. Not sure what to make of it. As with most other Three.js material, there's zero documentation on this.

Comment: http://spotted-triforce.com/other_files/example/uvs.html

Yes, there are other meshes in there, which is another thing that drove me crazy for the longest time. I found out that for each mesh I have in my maya scene when i export into obj, I get 3 meshes: One named "default", one with the name of the mesh from my maya scene, and one without a name. And it's actually the mesh without a name that contains all of the geometry.

Answer (score -2):

OMG! After running my head through the wall, I finally found the solution!

I've discovered that the problem was not as much a distortion of the texture as it was a random swapping of uv faces. That's right! For some reason, the webGL renderer randomly swapped some faces of the object with others.

Out of total coincidence I turned my mesh into quads instead of triangles and, voila!, that fixed everything. QUADS!!! I wasted friggin 3 solid days on triangles!!!